# Should I save BlobServiceClient & BlobContainerClient for the life of my app?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

Are `BlobServiceClient` & `BlobContainerClient` lightweight like `DbContext` so it's fine to instantiate them anytime needed?

Or do they take appreciable time to construct and therefore I should create them when my app starts and keep those objects for the life of the app (figure a month max because Azure app service moves a web app monthly to apply Windows updates to each system)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest AzureSDKs it is recommended to instantiate BlobServiceClient as singleton.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/lifetime-management-and-thread-safety-guarantees-of-azure-sdk-net-clients/

Answer (score 0):

> Are BlobServiceClient & BlobContainerClient lightweight like DbContext
> so it's fine to instantiate them anytime needed?

That's correct. Instantiating BlobServiceClient and BlobContainerClient are really lightweight operations which do not make any network calls at the time of instantiation. Only when you perform any operations on the storage account (using BlobServiceClient) or container (BlobContainerClient), network calls are made.

Comment: Is there any downside to instantiating them once and keeping them? I'm putting all my BLOB access code in a singleton service and figure it's easiest to create the objects in the constructor of the service. Thank you

Comment: `Is there any downside to instantiating them once and keeping them?` - I don't see any downside in this approach. HTH.

Comment: @GauravMantri Are you sure about the `BlobServiceClient`? I think it instantiates the http pipeline. The `Get...Client` following it should be lightweight though.

Comment: My answer was based on the network request being made at the time of instantiation. AFAIK, no network requests are being made. I may be wrong though.

Comment: @GauravMantri Fair enough. In the context of the question of the OP I think it's good to mention you should reuse the `BlobServiceClient` for the lifetime of the app, but for other reasons than solely the time to construct it.